# How to update inserted field in trigger

Tags: sql-server, triggers, sql-server-2012

Ok, my situation is like this:

I have a table named Company, and I want to add a trigger after every record I add in this table that checks if the column Name does not end with 'LTD' then add 'LTD' at the end of the Name.

I get an error saying Incorrect syntax near ')'. How would I do this?

```
Create Trigger [Add_LTD] on Company
After Insert As
Update Company
Set Name = Name + ' LTD'
If Exists (Select Name 
From Inserted
Where Name Not Like '% LTD')
```

Comment: Which database server are you using?

Comment: I'm using SQL Server 2012

Answer (score 13):

You would need something like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [Add_LTD] on dbo.Company
AFTER INSERT AS
   UPDATE dbo.Company
   SET Name = Name + ' LTD'
   FROM Inserted i
   WHERE dbo.Company.CompanyID = i.CompanyID
     AND Name NOT LIKE '% LTD'
```

You need to join the rows in `Inserted` to your underlying table (in order to update just those rows that have been newly inserted), and the best way to do this is to use your primary key (something like a `CompanyID`) to achieve this.