# Inserting only assigned properties with EF6

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

Is it possible to get `SaveChanges` to produce an `INSERT` statement containing only columns that have assigned values for the associated properties.

For example:

```
administrator.Login = login
administrator.PasswordSalt = salt
administrator.Password = hashed
administrator.CreatedBy = "xxx"

db.Administrators.Add(administrator)
db.SaveChanges()
```

Should only have four fields in the `INSERT` statement.  Right now, `SaveChanges` is adding all the fields, setting the unassigned properties to have a value of `NULL`, which prevents any default value being used.  Example: `CreatedDate` has a default of `getdate()`.

Answer (score 0):

There are at least two different ways to exclude property from `INSERT/UPDATE` statement in compile-time:

1) EDMX: go to entity and set `StoreGeneratedPattern` option for a property to `Computed` or `Identity`.

If CodeFirst is used: try `[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]` attribite instead.

2) Add `AFTER INSERT` trigger to SQL table  to update an inserted record with default values. [How to update inserted field in trigger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16511396/how-to-update-inserted-field-in-trigger)

I'm not sure it is possible to do in run-time in pure EF.